# glGenVertexArrays QOpenGLFunctions_3_1 read access violation

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

I have a problem within my project, using qt 5.5.1 and openGL GLSL. I try to display a skybox, and so i have created a class. This one inherits to QOpenGLFunctions_3_1. This last class contains a lot of gl function. Now on my skybox constructor, I initialize my arrays (vertex and index) and then i do this :

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vaoHandle);
glBindVertexArray(m_vaoHandle);

GLuint handle[2] = {0, 1};
glGenBuffers(2, handle);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 24 * 3 * sizeof(float), v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, handle[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36 * sizeof(GLuint), el, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I have an read access violation to the second line. If I place the two first line at the end, the read access violation is displayed to the first glBindBuffer...
A solution is to use glew, but I do not want.I took the code to an intial one which did not use this library (OpenGL 4.0 Shading Cookbook). Do you have any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: Just because you inherit from `QOpenGLFunctions_3_1` doesn't mean that you can use these functions. Have you properly initialized everything prior to use? Please show a **complete** example that demonstrates the problem. You don't need anything fancy, just one `main.cpp` with a class that shows the issue, and any necessary OpenGL initialization code in `main` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the initializeOpenGLFunctions(); line. This line is necessary in each class using QOpenGLFunctions_3_1 functions, and not only at the begining of the openGL pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

At most occasions I got the error the problem was that I tried to initialize something before OpenGl had set up. In your case I reckogn the problem will be that your skybox' vertex array's initialization is called before you set Glew up or GLUT. These OpenGl functions as glGenVertexArrays do not come from the opengl32.dll directly, it may be loaded from the GPU so that it must be initialized properly, so you can not use it without further initialization.